# What does [].forEach.call() do in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, arrays, foreach, ecmascript-5, nodelist

I was looking at some snippets of code, and I found multiple elements calling a function over a node list with a forEach applied to an empty array.

For example I have something like:

```
[].forEach.call( document.querySelectorAll('a'), function(el) {
   // whatever with the current node
});
```

but I can't understand how it works. Can anyone explain me the behaviour of the empty array in front of the forEach and how the `call` works?

Answer (score 243, accepted):

`[]` is an array.
This array isn't used at all.

It's being put on the page, because using an array gives you access to array prototypes, like `.forEach`.

This is just faster than typing `Array.prototype.forEach.call(...);`

Next, `forEach` is a function which takes a function as an input...

```
[1,2,3].forEach(function (num) { console.log(num); });
```

...and for each element in `this` (where `this` is array-like, in that it has a `length` and you can access its parts like `this[1]`) it will pass three things:

1. the element in the array
2. the index of the element (third element would pass `2`)
3. a reference to the array

Lastly, `.call` is a prototype which functions have (it's a function which gets called on other functions).
`.call` will take its first argument and replace `this` inside of the regular function with whatever you passed `call`, as the first argument (`undefined` or `null` will use `window` in everyday JS, or will be whatever you passed, if in "strict-mode"). The rest of the arguments will be passed to the original function.

```
[1, 2, 3].forEach.call(["a", "b", "c"], function (item, i, arr) {
    console.log(i + ": " + item);
});
// 0: "a"
// 1: "b"
// 2: "c"
```

Therefore, you're creating a quick way to call the `forEach` function, and you're changing `this` from the empty array to a list of all `<a>` tags, and for each `<a>` in-order, you are calling the function provided.

## EDIT

#### Logical Conclusion / Cleanup

Below, there's a link to an article suggesting that we scrap attempts at functional programming, and stick to manual, inline looping, every time, because this solution is hack-ish and unsightly.

I'd say that while `.forEach` is less helpful than its counterparts, `.map(transformer)`, `.filter(predicate)`, `.reduce(combiner, initialValue)`, it still serves purposes when all you really want to do is modify the outside world (not the array), n-times, while having access to either `arr[i]` or `i`.

So how do we deal with the disparity, as Motto is clearly a talented and knowledgeable guy, and I would like to imagine that I know what I'm doing/where I'm going (now and then...  ...other times it's head-first learning)?

The answer is actually quite simple, and something Uncle Bob and Sir Crockford would both facepalm, due to the oversight:

***clean it up***.

```
function toArray (arrLike) { // or asArray(), or array(), or *whatever*
  return [].slice.call(arrLike);
}

var checked = toArray(checkboxes).filter(isChecked);
checked.forEach(listValues);
```

Now, if you're questioning whether you need to do this, yourself, the answer may well be no...
This exact thing is done by...  ...every(?) library with higher-order features these days.
If you're using lodash or underscore or even jQuery, they're all going to have a way of taking a set of elements, and performing an action n-times.
If you aren't using such a thing, then by all means, write your own.

```
lib.array = (arrLike, start, end) => [].slice.call(arrLike, start, end);
lib.extend = function (subject) {
  var others = lib.array(arguments, 1);
  return others.reduce(appendKeys, subject);
};
```

#### Update for ES6(ES2015) and Beyond

Not only is a `slice( )`/`array( )`/etc helper method going to make life easier for people who want to use lists just like they use arrays (as they should), but for the people who have the luxury of operating in ES6+ browsers of the relatively-near future, or of "transpiling" in Babel today, you have language features built in, which make this type of thing unnecessary.

```
function countArgs (...allArgs) {
  return allArgs.length;
}

function logArgs (...allArgs) {
  return allArgs.forEach(arg => console.log(arg));
}

function extend (subject, ...others) { /* return ... */ }


var nodeArray = [ ...nodeList1, ...nodeList2 ];
```

Super-clean, and very useful.
Look up the ***Rest*** and ***Spread*** operators; try them out at the BabelJS site; if your tech stack is in order, use them in production with Babel and a build step.

---

There's no good reason not to be able to use the transform from non-array into array...  ...just don't make a mess of your code doing nothing *but* pasting that same ugly line, everywhere.

Comment: Now I'm a bit confused cause if I did:
    console.log(this);
I will always get the window object
And I thought that .call changes the value of this

Comment: `.call` *does* change the value of `this`, which is why you're using `call` with the forEach.  If forEach looks like `forEach (fn) { var i = 0; var len = this.length; for (; i < length; i += 1) { fn( this[i], i, this ); }` then by changing `this` by saying `forEach.call( newArrLike )` means that it will use that new object as `this`.

Comment: Yes, but still if I did `console.log(this)` inside the function of the `forEach` I should get the nodeList I added via `.call` because I changed the value of this however what confuses me is that `this` equals to Window and not the nodeList

Comment: @MuhammadSaleh `.call` doesn't change the value of `this` inside of what you pass to `forEach`, `.call` changes the value of `this` *inside of forEach*. If you are confused as to why `this` doesn't get passed from `forEach` into the function you wanted called, you should look up the behaviour of `this` in JavaScript.  As an addendum, applicable only here (and map/filter/reduce), there is a second argument to `forEach`, which sets `this` inside the function `arr.forEach(fn, thisInFn)` or `[].forEach.call(arrLike, fn, thisInFn);` or just use `.bind`; `arr.forEach(fn.bind(thisInFn));`

Comment: can you please clarify the meaning of this "The rest of the arguments will be passed to the original function."? do you mean [1,2,3]? i tried to console.log arr and got the first argument of call i.e. [a,b,c], not [1,2,3]. so it seems having stuff in the [1,2,3] array or not doesn't actually make a difference yes?

Comment: @thetrystero that's exactly the point. `[]` is just there as an array, so that you can `.call` the `.forEach` method, and change the `this` to the set you want to do work on. `.call` looks like this: `function (thisArg, a, b, c) { var method = this; method(a, b, c); }` except that there's internal black-magic to set `this` inside of `method` to equal what you passed as `thisArg`.

Comment: @thetrystero That's not likely helpful to you, right now; so let's try this: `function sum (a, b) { console.log(this.name); return a + b; }  var obj = { name: "test" }; sum.call( obj, 1, 2 ); // logs "test", returns 3`

Comment: so in short... Array.from()?

Comment: @zakius `Array.from(xs).forEach(f);` or `[...xs].forEach(f);`. Now, of course. Not when originally asked/answered.

Comment: @Norguard yeah, just I'm shocked that some basic things like iterating over node list were even more messy than today

Comment: @zakius The DOM is notoriously nasty, though has made a lot of strides in the past decade. The expectation would have been that you wrote a for loop, or a while loop, like any good Java/C programmer. The same is true of the `arguments` list inside of functions; it's not an array, it's a list. So more `for` loops it is.

Comment: @Norguard tbh I'm a fan of explicit for loops as you can clearly see what's going on but sometimes you need an array for anything else besides looping over it and then it breaks, that's unfortunate

Comment: This answer seems quite incomplete. Please explain why `[1, 2, 3].forEach.call` iterates three times, but `[].forEach.call` iterates more than zero times (once?). Also please explain why `[1, 2, 3].forEach.call` iterates through the indices `[0, 1, 2]` and not the array values `[1, 2, 3]`.

Comment: @LukeHutchison I believe that you are asking questions about the `forEach` function, and why its second argument is `i`, where its first argument is a value. Also, I believe you are asking questions about `call` and why it replaces references to `this` with whatever you pass in as its first argument. The question about how `forEach` works in general has little to do with this solution; the question about `Function.prototype.call` and `this` is either too deep and particular to explaining low level JS / host behaviour for this answer, or is best taken at face-value as explained.

Comment: @LukeHutchison to wit, `[].forEach.call(arr, fn)` will run for the length of `arr`, passed into `call`; not the array that is being used at the start of the `forEach` (as stated in the first two sentences, and elaborated thereafter). The length of the initial array is wholly inconsequential. When you use the second argument of the `forEach` function, you are using the index; the same as if you passed the function directly to `forEach` instead of `call`. Were you to log the first argument, you would get `"a", "b", "c"`, not `1, 2, 3`, due to how `call` replaces `this` and how `forEach` works.

Answer (score 64):

The [`querySelectorAll` method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/Document.querySelectorAll) returns a `NodeList`, which is similar to an array, but it's not quite an array. Therefore, it doesn't have a `forEach` method (which array objects inherit via `Array.prototype`).

Since a `NodeList` is similar to an array, array methods will actually work on it, so by using `[].forEach.call` you are invoking the `Array.prototype.forEach` method in the context of the `NodeList`, as if you had been able to simply do `yourNodeList.forEach(/*...*/)`.

Note that the empty array literal is just a shortcut to the expanded version, which you will probably see quite often too:

```
Array.prototype.forEach.call(/*...*/);
```

Comment: So, to clarify, there's no advantage in using `[].forEach.call(['a','b'], cb)` over `['a','b'].forEach(cb)` in everyday applications with standard arrays, just when trying to iterate over array-like structures that don't have `forEach` on their own prototype? Is that correct?

Comment: @MattFletcher: Yes that's correct. Both will work but why overcomplicate things? Just call the method directly on the array itself.

Comment: Cool, thanks. And I don't know why, maybe just for street cred, impressing old ladies in ALDI and such. I'll stick to `[].forEach()` :)

Comment: ```var section = document.querySelectorAll(".section");
      section.forEach((item)=>{
            console.log(item.offsetTop)
      })```

works well

Comment: @daslicht not in older versions of IE! (that _do_, however, support `forEach` on arrays, but not NodeList objects)

Answer (score 21):

The other answers have explained this code very well, so I'll just add a suggestion.

This is a good example of code that should be refactored for simplicity and clarity. Instead of using `[].forEach.call()` or `Array.prototype.forEach.call()` every time you do this, make a simple function out of it:

```
function forEach( list, callback ) {
    Array.prototype.forEach.call( list, callback );
}
```

Now you can call this function instead of the more complicated and obscure code:

```
forEach( document.querySelectorAll('a'), function( el ) {
   // whatever with the current node
});
```

Answer (score 7):

```
[].forEach.call( document.querySelectorAll('a'), function(el) {
   // whatever with the current node
});
```

It is basically the same as:

```
var arr = document.querySelectorAll('a');
arr.forEach(function(el) {
   // whatever with the current node
});
```

Answer (score 6):

It can be better written using

```
Array.prototype.forEach.call( document.querySelectorAll('a'), function(el) {

});
```

What is does is `document.querySelectorAll('a')` returns an object similar to an array, but it does not inherit from the `Array` type.
So we calls the `forEach` method from the `Array.prototype` object with the context as the value returned by `document.querySelectorAll('a')`

Answer (score 4):

Want to update on this old question:

The reason to use `[].foreach.call()` to loop through elements in the modern browsers is mostly over. We can use `document.querySelectorAll("a").foreach()` directly.

> NodeList objects are collections of nodes, usually returned by
>   properties such as Node.childNodes and methods such as
>   document.querySelectorAll().
>
> Although NodeList is not an Array, **it is possible to iterate over it
>   with forEach()**. It can also be converted to a real Array using
>   Array.from().
>
> However, some older browsers have not implemented NodeList.forEach()
>   nor Array.from(). This can be circumvented by using
>   Array.prototype.forEach() — see this document's Example.

Answer (score 3):

An empty array has a property `forEach` in its prototype which is a Function object. (The empty array is just an easy way to obtain a reference to the `forEach` function that all `Array` objects have.) Function objects, in turn, have a `call` property which is also a function. When you invoke a Function's `call` function, it runs the function with the given arguments. The first argument becomes `this` in the called function.

You can find documentation for the `call` function [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call). Documentation for `forEach` is [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach).

Answer (score 3):

Lots of good info on this page (see [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16053538/3029276)+[answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16053436/3029276)+[comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16053357/what-does-foreach-call-do-in-javascript#comment96252493_16053538)), but I recently had the same question as the OP, and it took some digging to get the whole picture. So, here's a short version:

The goal is to use [`Array`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array) methods on an array-like [`NodeList`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NodeList) that doesn't have those methods itself.

An older pattern co-opted Array's methods via [`Function.call()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call), and used an array literal (`[]`) rather than than `Array.prototype` because it was shorter to type:

```
[].forEach.call(document.querySelectorAll('a'), a => {})
```

A newer pattern (post ECMAScript 2015) is to use [`Array.from()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/from):

```
Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('a')).forEach(a => {})
```

Answer (score 1):

Just add one line:

```
NodeList.prototype.forEach = HTMLCollection.prototype.forEach = Array.prototype.forEach;
```

And voila!

```
document.querySelectorAll('a').forEach(function(el) {
  // whatever with the current node
});
```

Enjoy :—)

**Warning:** NodeList is a global class. Don't use this recomendation if you writing public library. However it's very convenient way for increasing self-efficacy when you work on website or node.js app.

Answer (score 1):

Just a quick and dirty solution I always end up using. I wouldn't touch prototypes, just as good practice. Of course, there are a lot of ways to make this better, but you get the idea.

```
const forEach = (array, callback) => {
  if (!array || !array.length || !callback) return
  for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
    callback(array[i], i);
  }
}

forEach(document.querySelectorAll('.a-class'), (item, index) => {
  console.log(`Item: ${item}, index: ${index}`);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

`[]` always returns a new array, it is equivalent to `new Array()` but is guaranteed to return an array because `Array` could be overwritten by the user whereas `[]` can not. So this is a safe way to get the prototype of `Array`, then as described, `call` is used to execute the function on the arraylike nodelist (this).

> Calls a function with a given this value and arguments provided
>   individually. [mdn](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call)

Comment: While `[]` will in fact always return an array, while `window.Array` can be overwritten with anything (in all old browsers), so too can `window.Array.prototype.forEach` be overwritten with anything. There is no guarantee of safety in either case, in browsers which don't support getters/setters or object sealing/freezing (freezing causing its own extensibility issues).

Comment: Feel free to edit the answer to add the extra information regarding the possibility of overwriting the `prototype` or it's methods: `forEach`.

Answer (score 0):

[Norguard](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16053538/1355416) explained *WHAT* `[].forEach.call()` does and [James Allardice](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16053436/1355416) *WHY* we do it: because querySelectorAll returns a `NodeList` that doesn't have a forEach method...

Unless you have modern browser like Chrome 51+, Firefox 50+, Opera 38, Safari 10.

If not you can add a [Polyfill](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NodeList/forEach#Polyfill):

```
if (window.NodeList && !NodeList.prototype.forEach) {
    NodeList.prototype.forEach = function (callback, thisArg) {
        thisArg = thisArg || window;
        for (var i = 0; i < this.length; i++) {
            callback.call(thisArg, this[i], i, this);
        }
    };
}
```

Answer (score 0):

let's say you have : `const myList= document.querySelectorAll("p");`
This will return an list/array of all

in your HTML.
Now `Array.prototype.forEach.call(myList, myCallback)`
is equivalent to `[].forEach.call(myList, myCallback)`
where 'myCallback' is a callback function.
You are basically running the callback function on each element of myList.
Hope this helped you!

Answer (score -1):

I don't know if there is any restriction, but it works.
I turned the nodeList into an **iterator object** using the **spread operator** and **mapped** it:

```js
let _btns = document.querySelectorAll('.btn');

[..._btns].map(function(elem, i) {
  elem.addEventListener('click', function (e) {
    console.log(elem.textContent);
  })
})
```

```css
.btn {
  padding: 5px; 
  color:#fff; 
  background-color: darkred; 
  text-align:center;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<button class="btn">button 1</button>
<button class="btn">button 2</button>
```