# Intersecting texts to find common words

Tags: javascript, regex, string, text

I'm trying to find out which would be the most optimal way of intersection a set of texts and find the common words in them. Given this scenario:

```
var t1 = 'My name is Mary-Ann, and I come from Kansas!';
var t2 = 'John, meet Mary, she comes from far away';
var t3 = 'Hi Mary-Ann, come here, nice to meet you!';
```

intersection result should be:

```
var result =["Mary"];
```

It should be able to ignore punctuation marks like `.,!?-`

Would a solution with regular expressions be optimal?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Here's a tested solution :

```
function intersect() {
   var set = {};
   [].forEach.call(arguments, function(a,i){
     var tokens = a.match(/\w+/g);
     if (!i) {
       tokens.forEach(function(t){ set[t]=1 });
     } else {
       for (var k in set){
         if (tokens.indexOf(k)<0) delete set[k];
       }
     }
   });
   return Object.keys(set);
}
```

This function is variadic, you can call it with any number of texts :

```
console.log(intersect(t1, t2, t3)) // -> ["Mary"] 

console.log(intersect(t1, t2)) // -> ["Mary", "from"] 

console.log(intersect()) // -> []
```

If you need to support non English languages, then this regex won't be enough because of the poor support of Unicode in JavaScript regexes. Either you use a [regex library](https://github.com/slevithan/xregexp/blob/master/README.md#unicode) or you define your regex by explicitly excluding characters as in `a.match(/[^\s\-.,!?]+/g);` (this will probably be enough for you) .

---

**Detailed explanation :**

The idea is to fill a set with the tokens of the first text and then remove from the set the tokens missing in the other texts.

1. The set is a JavaScript object used as a map. Some purists would have used `Object.create(null)` to avoid a prototype, I like the simplicity of `{}`.
2. As I want my function to be [variadic](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variadic_function), I use [`arguments`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions_and_function_scope/arguments) instead of defining the passed texts as explicit arguments.
3. `arguments` isn't a real array, so to iterate over it you need either a `for` loop or a trick like `[].forEach.call`. It works because `arguments` is ["array-like"](https://www.inkling.com/read/javascript-definitive-guide-david-flanagan-6th/chapter-7/array-like-objects).
4. To tokenize, I simply use [`match`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match) to match words, nothing special here (see note above regarding better support of other languages, though)
5. I use `!i` to check if it's the first text. In that case, I simply copy the tokens as properties in the set. A value must be used, I use `1`. In the future, [ES6 sets](http://www.nczonline.net/blog/2012/09/25/ecmascript-6-collections-part-1-sets/) will make the intent more obvious here.
6. For the following texts, I iterate over the elements of the sets (the keys) and I remove the ones which are not in the array of tokens (`tokens.indexOf(k)<0`)
7. Finally, I return the elements of the sets because we want an array. The simplest solution is to use [`Object.keys`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys).

Comment: "What does [].forEach.call() does in JavaScript?" http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16053357/what-does-foreach-call-does-in-javascript

Comment: @MatthewLock Do you mean I should have explained that point ?

Comment: Well that link will do.

Comment: It's clever code but I am still trying to follow it.

Comment: It could have been one statement and a little less "verbose" with `reduce` instead of `forEach` but I prefer it to be more readable.

Comment: @MatthewLock If there's another step that's unclear, please ask.

Comment: The whole thing is unclear to me, could you explain it all? I'm sure others would find that helpful too.

Comment: @MatthewLock OK, I do it, it will be long and detailed :)