# Why it is not possible to call forEach on a nodeList?

Tags: javascript, arrays, foreach, nodelist

I am using a forEach to loop through a nodeList. My code is as follows

```
var array = document.querySelectorAll('items');

array.forEach(function (item) {
    console.log(item);
});
```

And this code throws an error as

> Uncaught TypeError: array.forEach is not a function

Then after reading few online blog articles i changed the code to this.

```
[].forEach.call(array, (function (item) {
    console.log(item);
}));
```

Could someone please explain why it is not possible to call forEach on a nodeList and what does the above second code piece do. :)

**Edit:** *7/25/2017*

This question does not valid for modern browsers. You can use forEach on node lists in them

> Although NodeList is not an Array, it is possible to iterate on it
>   using forEach(). It can also be converted to an Array using
>   Array.from().
>
> However some older browsers have not yet implemented
>   NodeList.forEach() nor Array.from(). But those limitations can be
>   circumvented by using Array.prototype.forEach() (more in this
>   document).

Ref: [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NodeList)

Comment: Check out [NodeList.js](https://github.com/eorroe/NodeList.js)

Comment: Try this one line NodeList patch http://stackoverflow.com/a/32644632/502860

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This is a fundamental thing in JavaScript: you can take a function from one object and *apply* to any other object. That is: call it with `this` set to the object you *apply* the function to. It is possible, because in JavaScript all property names etc. are (plainly speaking) identified by name. So despite `NodeList.length` being something different then `Array.length` the function `Array.forEach` can be *applied* to anything that exposes property `length` (and other stuff that `forEach` requires).

So what happens in your case is that:

- `querySelectorAll()` returns an object of type *NodeList*, which happens to expose `length` property and is enumerable (let's say it is accessible by `[]` operator); *NodeList* does not expose `forEach` function (as you can see i.e here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NodeList) - that's why it's impossible to call `forEach` directly on the results of `querySelectorAll()`
- `[].forEach` returns a function - this a *not so clever* shortcut for `Array.prototype.forEach`
- with `[].forEach.call(array, …)` this function is *applied* onto an object referenced by `array`, an object of type *NodeList* (that is `forEach` is invoked with `array` as `this` in function body, so when inside `forEach` there is `this.length` it refers to `length` in `array` despite `array` being *NodeList* and not real *Array*)
- this works, because `forEach` is using properties that *Array* and *NodeList* have in common; it would fail if, i.e. `forEach` wanted to use some property that *Array* has, but *NodeList* has not

Comment: You can use `forEach` on `nodeList` nowadays

Answer (score 4):

the `NodeList` object doesnt contain the method `forEach`, its a method of the [Array object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach). the below code:

```
[].forEach.call(array, (function (item) {
    console.log(item);
}));
```

is using the `forEach` method from array and passing it a `NodeList`.

Another option you have, and arguabiliy better, is to convert your `NodeList` into an array, like this:

```
var myArrayOfNodes = [].slice.call(NodeList);
```

This uses the Array objects `slice` [method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice) to create an array of nodes from a `NodeList`. This is a better aproach as you can then use an array rather then hacking an array-like object

Answer (score -1):

`querySelectorAll` gets the element in `array-like` object not an Array. So you need to use as you have in second code example.

Comment: sorry, what you mean?

Comment: As you pointed out, the returned value of `querySelectorAll` doesn't return an `Array` so we can't explicitly invoke `.forEach`. However, we can *duck typing* it by pass it  as this into `forEach` to get things done. The terminology might be different but I guess it's likely a duck typing.