# intercept clicks on links

Tags: javascript, angularjs

In an Angular app, is it possible to somehow intercept all clicks on links (or all links within the scope of a particular controller's view)? For example, if I want to intercept all clicks on links, and block clicks on youtube links, can this be done?

Ideally I'd prefer not to have to add any custom attributes or use a custom element to achieve this, i.e. the links should look just like regular HTML links.

Comment: how you add your html with links? where you get links?

Comment: @Grundy I add the links to the HTML view with `<a>` tags

Comment: Add an on-click function to the anchor tags. Or use the `document.addEventListener` to listen for all clicks, then do some logic for listening to anchor tags or YouTube links.

Comment: i mean `href` for this `<a>` you add tag angular, you really use angular? can you provide sample your js and html? if you know href for links - you can just remove it by some condition

Comment: @Grundy Yes, I'm really using Angular, the links are just normal HTML links, e.g. `<a href="http://youtube.com">I am a link</a>`

Comment: @LittleBobbyDropTables, this s static html? or you create it dynamically?

Comment: @Grundy it's static HTML

Comment: So, you can simple remove `href` attribute and output not `<a href="something" ... >Text Link</a>` but `<a>Text Link</a>`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With angular, you can add a directive for the element `<a>` and add a listener on `click`

```
app.directive('a', function() {
    return {
        restrict: 'E', // only Elements (<a>),
        link: function(scope, elm, attr) {
            // every time you click on the link
            elm.on('click', function($event) {
                console.log('event')
                $event.preventDefault()
                return false
            })
        }
    }
})
```

and Tada!

Now, if you want to block some URLs, you can access the href element inside the link function via `attr.href`, so you would do it this way:

```
app.directive('a', function() {
    return {
        restrict: 'E', // only Elements (<a>),
        link: function(scope, elm, attr) {
            // every time you click on the link
            elm.on('click', function($event) {
                // only some URLs
                if(attr.href.match(/youtube\.com/)) {
                    $event.preventDefault()
                    return false
                }
            })
        }
    }
})
```

Comment: angular already provide [this directive](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/a)

Comment: @Grundy you can have unlimited directives with the same name!

Comment: nope, you just replace it with last version if add a few same named directive

Comment: @Grundy no no, you can have as many directives as you want with the same name. see http://plnkr.co/edit/I0C9yQKqpLezC1MR5K8R?p=preview open your console and click on the link

Comment: @Grundy as you can see from angular's source code, directives are added, not replaced: https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/master/src/ng/compile.js#L880

Comment: its interesting :-) don't known that :-)

Comment: better link to [this line](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/master/src/ng/compile.js#L888), your link _add if new directive_.

Comment: I like your idea. Make an attribute directive with a different name. Two directives can be instantiated on the same element if done correctly.

Comment: @georgeawg you're right, although we can have directives with the same names. They all will be executed, not only the latest

Comment: @Utopik I tested it and your right. The second directive with the same name linked first. Nice to know. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

This solution uses vanilla JS:

```js
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", () => {
  document.querySelectorAll('a').forEach(a => {
    a.addEventListener("click", (event) => {
      event.preventDefault(); // Block the page from loading
      alert(a.href); // Show an alert with the url in the href
    })
  })
});
```

```html
<a href="https://stackoverflow.com">Click me</a>
```

Comment: This works but using the [`[].forEach.call` hack](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16053357/what-does-foreach-call-do-in-javascript) makes it harder for readers who don't know about the hack to understand the answer. Also, I'd not encourage using the hack, which obfuscates just to save a few characters. And compared with the new `NodeList.forEach` method, it doesn't even do that. I'll update the answer.

Answer (score 0):

I made a sample for that, based on jQuery.

```js
// Contents, Controls or document ready 
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('.block').find('a').each ( function(){
      $(this).click(function(){
         console.log('custom-action');
          return false;
      });
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="block">
    <div><a href="http://naver.com" target="_blank">OK</a></div>
</div>
```

Comment: if tags right - expected solution for _angularjs_ instead of jQuery