# Cannot assign to read only property of true - AngularJS

Tags: angularjs

I've got a problem with assigning some properties to `$scope.milestones` object in my code.

```
MilestonesService.query({ gameId: $stateParams.gameId }, function(data) {
    $scope.milestones = data;
    for(var i in $scope.milestones) {
        if($scope.milestones[i]._id) {
            $http.get('/admin/tasks/byMilestone/' + $scope.milestones[i]._id).success(function(tasks) {
                $scope.milestones[i].tasks = tasks.length;
                $scope.milestones[i].tasksSolved = tasks.length;
                tasks.forEach(function(task) {
                    if(!task.evaluate.accepted) $scope.milestones[i].tasksSolved -= 1;
                }); 
            }).error(function(err) {
                console.log(err);
            });
        }
    }
});
```

It throws an error to console: Cannot assign to read only property 'tasks' of true, problem is on lines with `$scope.milestones[i].tasks` and `$scope.milestones[i].tasksSolved`. Why I can't assign value and extend each `$scope.milestones` object?

Edit:
data

```
0: Resource
$$hashKey: "01J"
__v: 0
_id: "5664b44b4a502abc27613d7b"
assignedToGame: "5664a04eeff8972c24651371"
date: "2015-12-19T00:00:00.000Z"
description: "Haha"
solved: false
title: "Milestones works"
__proto__: Resource
$promise: Object
$resolved: true
length: 1
__proto__: Array[0]
```

$scope.milestones[i]:

```
$$hashKey: "01J"
__v: 0
_id: "5664b44b4a502abc27613d7b"
assignedToGame: "5664a04eeff8972c24651371"
date: "2015-12-19T00:00:00.000Z"
description: "Haha"
solved: false
title: "Milestones works"
__proto__: Resource
```

Comment: What is in your data object? The error says you don't have objects in that array, but have at least one boolean value.

Comment: Take a look at the edit in question :-)

Comment: How does an example `$scope.milestones[i]` object looks like?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you can see, the data object is not an array but an array-like javascript object with some additional properties, so `for(var i in $scope.milestones) {` will iterate over the object properties of `scope.milestones`, and will eventually reach `milestones.$resolved (===true)`, which is a boolean, so trying to access a member of it will throw the error in the question. However if it *was* an array it would be still a [bad practice to iterate over array indices with for..in](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3010840/loop-through-array-in-javascript).

For a quick workaround, you can change the `for..in` to :

```
for(var i = 0; i < $scope.milestones.length; i++) {
```

or use [Array.prototype.forEach.call](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16053357/what-does-foreach-call-do-in-javascript):

```
Array.prototype.forEach.call($scope.milestones, function(item) {
    if(item._id) {
        $http.get('/admin/tasks/byMilestone/' + item._id).success(function(tasks) {
            item.tasks = tasks.length;
            item.tasksSolved = tasks.length;
            tasks.forEach(function(task) {
                if(!task.evaluate.accepted) item.tasksSolved -= 1;
            }); 
        }).error(function(err) {
            console.log(err);
        });
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Replace with usual for

```
MilestonesService.query({ gameId: $stateParams.gameId }, function(data) {
    $scope.milestones = data;
    for(var i=0;i<$scope.milestones.length; i++) {
        if($scope.milestones[i]._id) {
            $http.get('/admin/tasks/byMilestone/' + $scope.milestones[i]._id).success(function(tasks) {
                $scope.milestones[i].tasks = tasks.length;
                $scope.milestones[i].tasksSolved = tasks.length;
                tasks.forEach(function(task) {
                    if(!task.evaluate.accepted) $scope.milestones[i].tasksSolved -= 1;
                }); 
            }).error(function(err) {
                console.log(err);
            });
        }
    }
});
```

or use underscore forEach:

```
MilestonesService.query({ gameId: $stateParams.gameId }, function(data) {
    $scope.milestones = data;
    _.forEach(function(milestone){
        if(milestone._id) {
            $http.get('/admin/tasks/byMilestone/' + milestone._id).success(function(tasks) {
                milestone.tasks = tasks.length;
                milestone.tasksSolved = tasks.length;
                tasks.forEach(function(task) {
                    if(!task.evaluate.accepted) milestone.tasksSolved -= 1;
                }); 
            }).error(function(err) {
                console.log(err);
            });
        }
    });
});
```