# Event listener for DIV and change content

Tags: javascript

i got blocks like these:

```
<div class="listener" id="123">
<h1>Title</h1>Some text...
<div class="container"></div>
</div>

<br>

<div class="listener" id="456">
<h1>Title</h1>Some text...
<div class="container"></div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.listener{width:500px;background:red;border:1px solid black}
```

JavaScript:

```
document.getElementByClassName("listener").addEventListener("click", function()

{

// get the id of the DIV
// put content inside the class=container inside the DIV with innerHTML

});
```

What should happen?

After clicking in one of those boxes:

- call the function
- get the ID of the clicked DIV
- put some content inside the DIV (DIV with class=container)

Please NO solution with `<a>` or jQuery.

Any idea? Thanks!

I have a Fiddle here: https://jsfiddle.net/wwp9jk8t/

Comment: See that SO question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3219758/detect-changes-in-the-dom

Comment: @roland — You've misread the question. It is asking how to change the DOM when a click event is received, not what event is fired when the DOM is changed.

Comment: You have two problems: 1. It's getElementsByClassName, not getElementByClassName and 2. you can't call addEventListener to a node list. You must select a node in the node list and then you can call addEventListener.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> `document.getElementByClassName("listener")` will return `nodelist` not a DOM element and you *can not* bind `click` event to over `array-like NodeList`. Use [`[].forEach.call`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16053357/what-does-foreach-call-do-in-javascript)/`for-loop` to iterate all the elements in `nodeList` and apply `adeventListener` to every element.

Also *note* typo `getElementByClassName`, it should be **`getElementsByClassName`**(plural)

Try this:

```js
[].forEach.call(document.getElementsByClassName("listener"), function(elem) {
  elem.addEventListener("click", function() {
    alert(this.id);//to get the id attribute of the clicked element..    
    this.getElementsByClassName("container")[0].innerHTML = "Hello World";
  });
})
```

```css
.listener {
  width: 500px;
  background: red;
  border: 1px solid black
}
```

```html
<div class="listener" id="123">
  <h1>Title</h1>Some text...
  <div class="container"></div>
</div>

<br>

<div class="listener" id="456">
  <h1>Title</h1>Some text...
  <div class="container"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: This is great! Is it possible to get the ID of the DIV too? Because it should load content via Ajax ('getdata.php?id=....')

Comment: Works great! I have to put the JS-code below the elements, right? The script doesn't work if reload new div-boxes with ids... any idea how to refresh the index of the elements in the dom?

Comment: Script should be placed after HTML before `</body>` or wrap in `DOMContentLoaded`..For dynamically added elements, you will have to bind event again..