# Javascript Equivalent of Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am having problem in converting jquery to javascript as my application requirement is not to use jquery and only in plain html and javascript. I know how to write the code in Jquery but unable to convert it in javascript. My code is as follows

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
  $('input[type="button"').click(function () {
     $(this).prop('disabled','disabled');
   });
 });
```

How to convert this code snippet to javascript.

Comment: Note that `$(this).prop('disabled','disabled');` is too much jQuery even when you are using jQuery in a general sense: saying `this.disabled=true` is more efficient *and* easier to read.

Comment: Further to what @nnnnnn said - even if you were going to use jQuery you should be setting the property to `true` rather than `'disabled'`..remember that `.prop` sets a property's value on a DOM element, rather than modifying an HTML attribute as per `.attr`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the `DOMContentLoaded` event as follow:

```js
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(event) {
  console.log("DOM fully loaded and parsed");
  var btns = document.querySelectorAll("input[type=button]");
  for (let i = 0; i < btns.length; i++) {
    btns[i].addEventListener("click", function() {
      //Do stuff
      console.log("button" + i +  "clicked");
    });
  }
});
```

Comment: `querySelector` will select only one element!

Comment: A node collection doesn't have a `forEach` method.

Comment: What about the `$(this).prop('disabled','disabled');` part?

Answer (score 7):

- Use [`window.onload`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/GlobalEventHandlers/onload) to handle `load-event` on the `window`
- [`document.querySelectorAll`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll) to select list of the elements within the document that match the specified group of selectors.
- [`[].forEach.call`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16053357/what-does-foreach-call-do-in-javascript) to iterate through selected elements.
- [`addEventListener`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener) to register the specified listener on the element.

```js
window.onload = function() {
  var elems = document.querySelectorAll('input[type="button"]');
  [].forEach.call(elems, function(el) {
    el.addEventListener('click', function() {
      this.disabled = true;
    });
  });
};
```

**Edit:** `document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () {});` could be used instead of `window.onload` but consider [*Browser compatibility*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/DOMContentLoaded#Browser_compatibility) as well. Another easier alternate would be to place your `<script>` as `last-child` of `<body>` without wrapping your `script` in any `load` handler.

Comment: +1 You can suggest using `document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(event){  });` instead of `window.onload`. Because `$(document).ready` is entirely different from `window.onload`

Comment: @RajaprabhuAravindasamy, That is what came in my mind first but someone suggested me to consider [__Browser compatibility__](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/DOMContentLoaded#Browser_compatibility)

Comment: Neither window load nor DOMContentLoaded are a direct replacement for jQuery's ready() handler, but at least using the load event avoids having to jump through hoops to support older browsers.

Comment: @Andy, [Filip](http://stackoverflow.com/users/44041/filip-dupanovi%C4%87) did edit it.. Thank you :)

Comment: Also, you missed the `$(this).prop('disabled','disabled');` part.

Comment: @Andy, That was added later in [question](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/37044746/revisions).. Have updated the answer..

Comment: I'm not sure why you used `window.onload` over the `DOMContentLoaded` event because of browser compatibility, but then used `querySelectorAll`?

Comment: Quiet valid! `DOMContentLoaded` is supported since `IE9` but `querySelectorAll` sould be used since `IE8`.. Not sure OP is considering `<IE8`

Comment: I didn't realise `querySelectorAll` was available in IE8, thanks for the info :)