# javascript: call function by classname

Tags: javascript, function, getelementsbyclassname

Trying to create a script that is bound by className and calls another function.

I have this code working for first instance of className, but if I remove the `[0]` in the first line of the script it no longer works.

```
  <input type="text" value="NOTBound" class="NOTBound"/>
  <input type="text" value="Bound value 1" class="Bound"/>
  <input type="text" value="NOTBound" class="NOTBound"/>
  <input type="text" value="Bound value 2" class="Bound"/>
  <script>
  inputBound = document.getElementsByClassName('Bound')[0];
  inputBound.onfocus = function() {
      var input = this.value;
      formFunct(input);
  }
  function formFunct(input) {
      console.log('done did the form Funct: ' + input)
  }
  </script>
```

How do I get it to work for all inputs with `className="Bound"`?  I do not need a jQuery solution.

Thank you.

Comment: you have to iterate through all of them (there are two great answers below, but you can also use a regular **for** loop) (getElementsByClassName returns an array), unless you want to use a javascript library that does that for you.

Comment: You need to loop through `document.getElementsByClassName('Bound')` and apply the `onfocus` event for each element in the list.

Comment: Really appreciate everyone jumping in so quickly.  Thank you to all!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> Use a loop to iterate all elements.

Use [**`Array#forEach`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach), *`forEach()` method executes a provided function once per array element.*

Another alternate could to use [**`Array.from`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/from) over `HTMLCollection` returned by `getElementsByClassName` so that you can invoke `Array#` methods directly over returned result.

```js
var inputBound = document.getElementsByClassName('Bound');
[].forEach.call(inputBound, function(inputBound) {
  inputBound.onfocus = function() {
    var input = this.value;
    formFunct(input);
  }
})

function formFunct(input) {
  console.log('done did the form Funct: ' + input)
}
```

```html
<input type="text" value="NOTBound" class="NOTBound" />
<input type="text" value="Bound value 1" class="Bound" />
<input type="text" value="NOTBound" class="NOTBound" />
<input type="text" value="Bound value 2" class="Bound" />
```

**Notes:**

- Refer [*What does [].forEach.call() do in
  JavaScript?*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16053357/what-does-foreach-call-do-in-javascript)
  to understand `[].forEach.call`.
- As suggested in comments, you can use `for-loop` as well to iterate
  `HTMLCollection`.
- As far as [*Browser
  compatibility*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach#Browser_compatibility)
  is concerned, one could use
  [*Polyfill*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach#Polyfill)

Comment: That's a clever use of `.call`. Perhaps it's quite advanced for the OP (else he wouldn't have asked that), but it definetly is the best answer out there, great approach.

Comment: Or just a normal for loop, would be faster and supported by all browsers.

Comment: @briosheje, I have added a note about that.. Thanks ;)

Comment: Fascinating. It'll take me a while to wrap my head around this one.  Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

Iterate over `NodeList` and attach event handler to the element.

```js
// get all elements and convert to array
Array.from(document.getElementsByClassName('Bound'))
  // iterate overa array elements
  .forEach(function(ele) {
    // bind event handler
    ele.onfocus = function() {
      var input = this.value;
      formFunct(input);
    }
  });

function formFunct(input) {
  console.log('done did the form Funct: ' + input)
}
```

```html
<input type="text" value="NOTBound" class="NOTBound" />
<input type="text" value="Bound value 1" class="Bound" />
<input type="text" value="NOTBound" class="NOTBound" />
<input type="text" value="Bound value 2" class="Bound" />
```

Comment: I really like this one.  Simple and understandable.  Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

simply iterate all the `Node`(s) in a `NodeList`  (with a good old for-loop :))

```
inputBounds = document.getElementsByClassName('Bound');
for( var counter = 0; counter < inputBounds.length; inputBounds++ )
{
  inputBounds.item( counter ).onfocus = function() {
      var input = this.value;
      formFunct(input);
  }   
}
```