# JavaScript create multi level object

Tags: javascript, object

I want to create an object like this:

```
var exampleObject = {
    '1' : ['2','3','7'],
    '2' : ['4','7'],
    '4' : ['5','1','2']
  };
```

from a list of inputs fields:

```
<input type="checkbox" class="flat-red" name="1" value="2">
<input type="checkbox" class="flat-red" name="1" value="3">
<input type="checkbox" class="flat-red" name="1" value="7">
<input type="checkbox" class="flat-red" name="2" value="4">
<input type="checkbox" class="flat-red" name="2" value="7">
<input type="checkbox" class="flat-red" name="4" value="5">
<input type="checkbox" class="flat-red" name="4" value="1">
<input type="checkbox" class="flat-red" name="4" value="2">
```

The idea is that for each input with the same "name" attribute i would like to have the values from the "value" field in the input. I have tried different approaches but without success. Any suggestion on how i could achieve this?

Comment: It's not a JSON object, but a JS object.

Comment: when checked or all?

Comment: You could do it with javascript!

Comment: Who said it is a json object @zerkms?!

Comment: @IndritSholla you in the question subject?

Comment: It wasn't meant to be there, really sorry man. Coffee sometime doesn't work properly :D

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- Use [`document.querySelectorAll`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll) to select all `'.flat-red'` elements
- Use [`[].forEach.call`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16053357/what-does-foreach-call-do-in-javascript) to iterate elements

```js
var elems = document.querySelectorAll('.flat-red');
var obj = {};
[].forEach.call(elems, function(el) {
  if (!obj[el.name]) {
    obj[el.name] = [el.value];
  } else {
    obj[el.name].push(el.value);
  }
});
console.log(obj);
```

```html
<input type="checkbox" class="flat-red" name="1" value="2">
<input type="checkbox" class="flat-red" name="1" value="3">
<input type="checkbox" class="flat-red" name="1" value="7">
<input type="checkbox" class="flat-red" name="2" value="4">
<input type="checkbox" class="flat-red" name="2" value="7">
<input type="checkbox" class="flat-red" name="4" value="5">
<input type="checkbox" class="flat-red" name="4" value="1">
<input type="checkbox" class="flat-red" name="4" value="2">
```

**Using `Array#reduce`**

```js
var elems = document.querySelectorAll('.flat-red');
var a = [].reduce.call(elems, function(a, b) {
  return !a[b.name] && (a[b.name] = []), a[b.name].push(b.value), a;
}, {});
console.log(JSON.stringify(a, null, 4));
```

```html
<input type="checkbox" class="flat-red" name="1" value="2">
<input type="checkbox" class="flat-red" name="1" value="3">
<input type="checkbox" class="flat-red" name="1" value="7">
<input type="checkbox" class="flat-red" name="2" value="4">
<input type="checkbox" class="flat-red" name="2" value="7">
<input type="checkbox" class="flat-red" name="4" value="5">
<input type="checkbox" class="flat-red" name="4" value="1">
<input type="checkbox" class="flat-red" name="4" value="2">
```

**If getting `object` based on `checked` status**

```js
var allElems = document.querySelectorAll('.flat-red');
[].forEach.call(allElems, function(el) {
  el.addEventListener('change', function() {
    var elems = document.querySelectorAll('.flat-red:checked');
    var a = [].reduce.call(elems, function(a, b) {
      return !a[b.name] && (a[b.name] = []), a[b.name].push(b.value), a;
    }, {});
    console.log(JSON.stringify(a, null, 4));
  });
});
```

```html
<input type="checkbox" class="flat-red" name="1" value="2">
<input type="checkbox" class="flat-red" name="1" value="3">
<input type="checkbox" class="flat-red" name="1" value="7">
<input type="checkbox" class="flat-red" name="2" value="4">
<input type="checkbox" class="flat-red" name="2" value="7">
<input type="checkbox" class="flat-red" name="4" value="5">
<input type="checkbox" class="flat-red" name="4" value="1">
<input type="checkbox" class="flat-red" name="4" value="2">
```

Answer (score 1):

using reduce:

```js
var elems = document.querySelectorAll('.flat-red');

var r = Array.from(elems) //transform to array
.reduce((ac,x) =>{
  if(!ac[x.name])
    ac[x.name] = [];
  
  ac[x.name].push(x.value)
  return ac;
} ,{})
        
console.log(r)
```

```html
<input type="checkbox" class="flat-red" name="1" value="2">
<input type="checkbox" class="flat-red" name="1" value="3">
<input type="checkbox" class="flat-red" name="1" value="7">
<input type="checkbox" class="flat-red" name="2" value="4">
<input type="checkbox" class="flat-red" name="2" value="7">
<input type="checkbox" class="flat-red" name="4" value="5">
<input type="checkbox" class="flat-red" name="4" value="1">
<input type="checkbox" class="flat-red" name="4" value="2">
```

Comment: Thank you, this works fine too. I just marked the below answer because i am not familiar with the reduce function. Have a nice day!

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with `for()` loop and one object.

```js
var result = {}
var inputs = document.querySelectorAll('.flat-red');

for (var i = 0; i < inputs.length; i++) {
  var name = inputs[i].name;
  var val = inputs[i].value;
  if (!result[name]) {
    result[name] = [];
  }
  result[name].push(val);
}

console.log(result)
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="checkbox" class="flat-red" name="1" value="2">
<input type="checkbox" class="flat-red" name="1" value="3">
<input type="checkbox" class="flat-red" name="1" value="7">
<input type="checkbox" class="flat-red" name="2" value="4">
<input type="checkbox" class="flat-red" name="2" value="7">
<input type="checkbox" class="flat-red" name="4" value="5">
<input type="checkbox" class="flat-red" name="4" value="1">
<input type="checkbox" class="flat-red" name="4" value="2">
```

Comment: jquery solution to a vanilla javascript tagged question ?!?

Comment: @Jamiec Thanks, didn't watch the tags, i updated my answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this pretty easily with a loop across the elements building up a blank `object` as you go.

```js
document.getElementById("go").addEventListener("click",function(){
  var elems = document.querySelectorAll(".flat-red");
  var result = {};
  
  for(var i=0;i<elems.length;i++){
    var elem = elems[i];
    var name =elem.getAttribute("name");
    if(!result.hasOwnProperty(name)){
       result[name] = [];  
    }
    result[name].push(elem.value);
  };
  console.log(result)
});
```

```html
<input type="checkbox" class="flat-red" name="1" value="2">
<input type="checkbox" class="flat-red" name="1" value="3">
<input type="checkbox" class="flat-red" name="1" value="7">
<input type="checkbox" class="flat-red" name="2" value="4">
<input type="checkbox" class="flat-red" name="2" value="7">
<input type="checkbox" class="flat-red" name="4" value="5">
<input type="checkbox" class="flat-red" name="4" value="1">
<input type="checkbox" class="flat-red" name="4" value="2">

<button id="go">Do it</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
let result = {};
let inputs = document.querySelectorAll('input');
for (let input of inputs) {
  result[input.name] = result[input.name] || [];
  result[input.name].push(input.value);
}
document.write(JSON.stringify(result));
```

```html
<input type="checkbox" class="flat-red" name="1" value="2">
<input type="checkbox" class="flat-red" name="1" value="3">
<input type="checkbox" class="flat-red" name="1" value="7">
<input type="checkbox" class="flat-red" name="2" value="4">
<input type="checkbox" class="flat-red" name="2" value="7">
<input type="checkbox" class="flat-red" name="4" value="5">
<input type="checkbox" class="flat-red" name="4" value="1">
<input type="checkbox" class="flat-red" name="4" value="2">
```