# How to Alert target id of multiple sets of ul list elements?

Tags: javascript, html

I have list elements as below :

```
<ul id="listSet">
<li id="dy1">Dynamic values</li>
<li id="dy2">Dynamic values</li>
</ul>
```

`id` of `li` is dynamic and populated from database.

When i click any item i.e Dynamic Values their `id` is shown as alert .

Code to show alert :

```
function getEventTarget(e) {
    e = e || window.event;
    return e.target || e.srcElement; 
}

var ul = document.getElementById('listSet');
ul.onclick = function(event) {
    var target = getEventTarget(event);
    alert(target.id);
};
```

But i have multiple sets of `ul` which are retrieved from database , for example as :

```
<ul id="listSet">
<li id="dy1">Dynamic values</li>
<li id="dy2">Dynamic values</li>
</ul>

<ul id="listSet">
<li id="dy3">Dynamic values</li>
<li id="dy4">Dynamic values</li>
</ul>


<ul id="listSet">
<li id="dy5">Dynamic values</li>
<li id="dy6">Dynamic values</li>
</ul>
```

Using same script for alert , shows click alert for only first set of `ul` ,
How to show alert when click any item under `li` with `ul id = "listSet"`  ?

Thanks

Comment: [___There must not be multiple `elements` in a `document` that have the same `id` value.___](https://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/global-attributes.html#common.attrs.id)

Comment: thank you @Rayon ,missed out class

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> [***There must not be multiple `elements` in a `document` that have the same `id` value.***](https://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/global-attributes.html#common.attrs.id)

Use `class` instead of `ID` attribute and [`getElementsByClassName`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementsByClassName) or [`querySelectorAll`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll) to select elements.

[`[].forEach.call`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16053357/what-does-foreach-call-do-in-javascript) is used to iterate elements having `length` property, `for-loop` could be used as well.

```js
function getEventTarget(e) {
  e = e || window.event;
  return e.target || e.srcElement;
}

var ul = document.getElementsByClassName('listSet');
[].forEach.call(ul, function(el) {
  el.onclick = function(event) {
    var target = getEventTarget(event);
    alert(target.id);
  };
});
```

```html
<ul class="listSet">
  <li id="dy1">Dynamic values</li>
  <li id="dy2">Dynamic values</li>
</ul>

<ul class="listSet">
  <li id="dy3">Dynamic values</li>
  <li id="dy4">Dynamic values</li>
</ul>


<ul class="listSet">
  <li id="dy5">Dynamic values</li>
  <li id="dy6">Dynamic values</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1):

The HTML spec required the `ID` attribute to be unique in a page:

> This attribute assigns a name to an element. This name must be unique in a document.

If you have several elements with the same ID, your HTML is not valid.

So, `getElementById()` should only ever return one element. You can't make it return multiple elements.

You can use getElementByClassName then use some kind of loop on all retrieved elements and attach events on them.

Answer (score 1):

elements can't have same ID but could have same class name anyway with do not need class name or id attr of ul element,
it's easy to handle it with Jquery
use below code

```
$("li").on("click",function(){
id=$(this).attr("id");
alert(id);
});
```

and see the live demo at below link
https://jsfiddle.net/kjakzc7d/