# why not my all div inside the div is getting the height of firstChild

Tags: javascript, html, css

I want to make my all div height equal to the first child of the inside div 
here I have three div `p , p2 , p3` which is inside of another div called(class) `r` , I want to make my `p2 , p3` same height to `p`.

**HTML**

```
<div>
  <div class="r">
    <div class="p">fgdsgs</div>
    <div class="p2">sdgdfg</div>
    <div class="p3">sdgdfg</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.p,.p2,.p3{
  display:inline-block;
  width:80px;
}
.p{
  height:50px;
}
```

**JS**

```
var firstChild = document.querySelector(".r:first-child");
var descendant = firstChild.querySelectorAll(".p, .p2,.p3");

[].forEach.call(descendant, function(itm){ 
  itm.style.backgroundColor = "green";
  var ch = document.getElementsByClassName("p").clientHeight;
  for(var i = 0 ;i < ch.length; i++ ){
  itm.style.height = ch[i] + "px";
  }
});
```

Demo - https://jsfiddle.net/104sn7mu/13/

**Edit 1**

loops added

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/104sn7mu/10/

Comment: is changing height using script is required ? Why not from CSS?

Comment: would a jquery answer work?

Comment: because im learning javascript

Comment: @RajaprabhuAravindasamy i've added a loop inside that

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/104sn7mu/14/

Answer (score 2):

You have selected `.r` and stored first child in `var firstChild`, so use that as below,

```js
var firstChild = document.querySelector(".r:first-child");
var descendant = firstChild.querySelectorAll(".p, .p2,.p3");

[].forEach.call(descendant, function(itm){ 
  itm.style.backgroundColor = "green";
  var ch = firstChild.clientHeight;
  itm.style.height = ch + "px";
});
```

```css
.p,.p2,.p3{
  display:inline-block;
  width:80px;
}
.p{
  height:50px;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <div class="r">
    <div class="p">fgdsgs</div>
    <div class="p2">sdgdfg</div>
    <div class="p3">sdgdfg</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I haven't seen the `[].forEach...` syntax before, it looks like its creating an "on the fly" empty array, but then if its empty - how can you foreach over the elements of an empty array?

Comment: @the_velour_fog, see [`Function#call`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call).

Comment: @AndréDion thanks, yes now I see. Basically `descendant = firstChild.querySelectorAll(".p, .p2,.p3");` makes `descendant` a [node list](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/NodeList) comprising all the elements containing the `p`,`p2`,`p3` classes. Then  `[].forEach.call` is basically "borrowing" the `forEach` from the [array prototype](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) and calling it using  `descendant` as this and passing in the callback. im guessing its because nodelist doesnt have `forEach`?

Comment: so its equivalent to to `descendant.forEach( function(itm) { 
 //... })`

Comment: @the_velour_fog you can read a proper explanation on this stack answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16053357/what-does-foreach-call-do-in-javascript

Answer (score 0):

you can use the variable you made earlier like this:

```
var firstChild = document.querySelector(".r:first-child");
var descendant = firstChild.querySelectorAll(".p, .p2,.p3");

[].forEach.call(descendant, function(itm){ 
  itm.style.backgroundColor = "blue";
  var ch = firstChild.clientHeight;
  itm.style.height = ch + "px";
});
```

Comment: What are you trying to achieve with the loop? are you trying to make the blocks slowly increase in size?

Answer (score 0):

```js
var r = document.querySelectorAll(".r");
r.forEach(function(pel){
var rChildren = pel.querySelectorAll(".p, .p2,.p3");
rChildren.forEach(function(el){ 
  el.style.backgroundColor = "green";
  var ch = rChildren[0].clientHeight; // 1st child clientHeight of all elements under div having class r
  el.style.height = ch + "px";
});
});
```

```css
.p,.p2,.p3{
  display:inline-block;
  width:80px;
}
.p{
  height:50px;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <div class="r">
    <div class="p">fgdsgs</div>
    <div class="p2">sdgdfg</div>
    <div class="p3">sdgdfg</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

```js
var r = document.querySelectorAll(".r");
r.forEach(function(pel){
var rChildren = pel.querySelectorAll(".p, .p2,.p3");
rChildren.forEach(function(el){ 
  el.style.backgroundColor = "green";
  var ch = rChildren[0].clientHeight; // 1st child clientHeight of all elements under div having class r
  el.style.height = ch + "px";
});
});
```

```css
.p,.p2,.p3{
  display:inline-block;
  width:80px;
}
.p{
  height:50px;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <div class="r">
    <div class="p">fgdsgs</div>
    <div class="p2">sdgdfg</div>
    <div class="p3">sdgdfg</div>
  </div>
  <br><br>
    <div class="r">
    <div class="p">fgdsgs</div>
    <div class="p2">sdgdfg</div>
    <div class="p3">sdgdfg</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: check the loop please

Comment: @Anjali made an edit i think it much more clear now.