# AJAX request no longer pointing to correct variable in success callback method

Tags: javascript, html, ajax, flask

Say for example, in my HTML file I have the following table rows in a table, where {{ }} are just variables:

```html
<tr id="{{ object.id }}">
    <td class="name">{{ object.name }}</td>
</tr>
<tr id="{{ object.id }}">
    <td class="name">{{ object.name }}</td>
</tr>
```

Then in my JavaScript file I have the following code:

```js
var rows = document.getElementsByTagName("tr"); 

for (var r = 0; r < rows.length; r++){
        var tr = rows[r];
        var id = tr.id;

        $.ajax({
            url: "/some-link/" + id,
            success: function(some_json){
                some_json = JSON.parse(some_json);
                var td = document.createElement("td");
                td.innerHTML = some_json;

                //Problem is the following tr is referring to the last tr in the for loop by the time the AJAX request is complete
                tr.appendChild(td);
            }
        });
    }
```

The result I get is:

```html
<tr id="{{ object.id }}">
    <td class="name">{{ object.name }}</td>
</tr>
<tr id="{{ object.id }}">
    <td class="name">{{ object.name }}</td>
    <td>SomeJSON from when rows was 0 in the for loop</td>
    <td>SomeJSON from when rows was 1 in the for loop</td>
</tr>
```

However, my intended result was:

```html
<tr id="{{ object.id }}">
    <td class="name">{{ object.name }}</td>
    <td>SomeJSON from when rows was 0 in the for loop</td>
</tr>
<tr id="{{ object.id }}">
    <td class="name">{{ object.name }}</td>
    <td>SomeJSON from when rows was 1 in the for loop</td>
</tr>
```

I know I can fix this by adding to the AJAX request `async: false` but I want to keep it asynchronous.

Any help will be much appreciated.

Comment: have you tried changing `for (var rows = 0; rows < tableRows.length; rows++){ var tr = tableRows[rows];` to `for (var i = 0; i < rows.length; rows++){
        var tr = rows[i];`? Seems like that's what you want to do. If that doesn't work, post all of your code - `tableRows` isn't in your code.

Comment: because `$.ajax` is asynchronous, by the time the success is called, tr will be `tableRows[tableRows.length - 1]` for ALL success functions

Comment: @MichaelCoker - why would changing a variable name make a difference?

Comment: @JaromandaX `rows` is all `tr`'s, then OP's using it as the counter for a loop, but referencing `tableRows`, which doesn't exist in the code.

Comment: sorry, misread the code in the question :p

Comment: your code is still not going to do anything resembling useful - where is `tableRows` defined?

Comment: @Tuffail please edit your code it's accurate

Comment: should `var rows = document.getElementsByTagName("tr");` be `var tableRows = document.getElementsByTagName("tr");`

Comment: I've fixed the issue, sorry I was trying to modify the code from the actual code to make it simpler to understand and I forgot to change some variable names

Comment: anyway, the answer below should work for you - given the appropriate changes to variable names

Comment: @JaromandaX Yes, it did indeed work. Thanks for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could it be an issue involving closures with Javascript? If you define a function inside of the for loop and assign the variables inside of the function, they will retain their scope through the success callback.

An alternate (cleaner/more elegant) solution would rewrite the `for` loop and function call into an [Array.prototype.forEach()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) (thanks [Jaromanda X](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42450411/ajax-request-no-longer-pointing-to-correct-variable-in-success-callback-method/42450464#comment72044825_42450464))

[We are using [] as a shorthand for accessing the Array prototype, and using .call in order to create the scoped function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16053357/what-does-foreach-call-do-in-javascript)

Inside of the function, the variables are scoped. Previously, every ajax success callback referenced the same variable (which was the variable when the async requests returned)

```
[].forEach.call(rows, function(tr) { 
        var id = tr.id;

        $.ajax({
            url: "/some-link/" + id,
            success: function(some_json){
                some_json = JSON.parse(some_json);
                var td = document.createElement("td");
                td.innerHTML = some_json;

                tr.appendChild(td);
            }
        });

});
```

Comment: an even cleaner solution is to replace the for loop with `[].forEach.call(tableRows, function(tr) { ... });`

Comment: Great idea, I just started my trek home and will edit in an hour or so, much appreciated!

Comment: @Hodrobond Hey I've edited the code, I made some errors with the variable names when I tried to make the code easier to understand from my actual code. Please could you update your answer

Comment: Certainly, just give me about an hour or so, and I'll be back in front of a computer :)

Comment: @Hodrobond Your solution has indeed worked thank you for your help

Comment: @Hodrobond - real programmers use mobile phones to answer SO questions :p

Comment: @JaromandaX It's a little difficult if I go into tunnels and lose connection =) . Also, answer updated (thanks again)!