# REACT DROPZONE: Get data:images after upload

Tags: javascript, reactjs, dropzone.js

As topic, I want get `data:images` after upload. I get that if only upload one image. If multiple images how to array it in console?

```
constructor(props) {
  super(props);
  this.state = {
    image: null
  };
}

onDropMain(mainImage) {
    var that = this
    let reader = new FileReader()
    reader.readAsDataURL(mainImage[0])
    reader.onloadend = function() {
        var result = reader.result
        that.setState({
            mainImage: result
        });
    }
    console.log(reader);
}
```

This is how I get single `data:images`, but how about multiple images? Anyone has experience in this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To read multiple images:

**1.** First define a function that will read a single file.

**2.** Use any loop to call that function for each entry of the array.

**3.** Use array in `state` variable to store the result, instead of a single variable.

```
constructor(props) {
  super(props);
  this.state = {
    image: []
  };
}
```

Use this function to read multiple files:

```
onDropMain(mainImage) {
    var that = this;

    function read(file){
        let Reader = new FileReader();
        Reader.onload = function (event) {
            let image = that.state.image.slice();
            image.push(event.target.result);
            that.setState({image}, () => console.log(image));
        };
        Reader.readAsDataURL(file);
    }

    if (mainImage && mainImage.length) {
        [].forEach.call(mainImage, read);
    }    
}
```

Check the [answers of this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16053357/what-does-foreach-call-do-in-javascript) for details about `[].forEach.call(mainImage, read)`.