# Click on multiple elements same class name

Tags: javascript, dom

I have multiple html elements with same class name i want to know which element clicked in pure javascript

```
<a href="#" data-wow="1" class="wow">link a</a>
<a href="#" data-wow="2" class="wow">link a</a>
<a href="#" data-wow="3" class="wow">link a</a>
```

in javascript i tried a lot of solutions but all i found working with one element only

what i wrote so far

```
    var dd = document.getElementsByClassName('messages-email');

    dd.onclick() = function(ee){
      // if i clicked the first link i want to get data-wow which is 1
      // and if i clicked the third one i wanna get data-wow which is 3
      console.log('i want the clicked elemet attribute ')
    }
```

Comment: Where is your element with the class `messages-email`?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There are a few issues with your code:

1. There is no element with the class `message-email` in your markup. I suppose it's simply a mistake when you're attempting to demonstrate your markup, and that you are referring to the anchor elements with the `wow` class
2. `document.getElementsByClassName` returns a Node collection. You will have to iterate through the collection in order to bind the click event. You can use [`Array.prototype.forEach.call(<NodeCollection>, function(element) { ... })` to iterate through your node collection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16053357/what-does-foreach-call-do-in-javascript)
3. Do not use `.onclick` to bind click event, as that will override any `onclick` handlers. You should be using `.addEventListener('click', function() {...})` instead
4. In order to access `data-wow` attribute, use the [HTML5 `dataset` API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/dataset)

With that in mind, here is a proof-of-concept example:

```js
var dd = document.getElementsByClassName('wow');

Array.prototype.forEach.call(dd, function(element) {
  element.addEventListener('click', function() {
    console.log('data-wow value is: ' + element.dataset.wow);
  });
});
```

```html
<a href="#" data-wow="1" class="wow">link a</a>
<a href="#" data-wow="2" class="wow">link a</a>
<a href="#" data-wow="3" class="wow">link a</a>
```

**Bonus:** If you are familiar with ES2015 (aka ES6), there is an even easier way to do this:

```js
const dd = document.getElementsByClassName('wow');

Array.from(dd).forEach(element => {
  element.addEventListener('click', () => {
    console.log('data-wow value is: ' + element.dataset.wow);
  });
});
```

```html
<a href="#" data-wow="1" class="wow">link a</a>
<a href="#" data-wow="2" class="wow">link a</a>
<a href="#" data-wow="3" class="wow">link a</a>
```

Comment: terrific, yea message-email was a mistake glad u caught it.<br> this is pretty good thank you.