# How to change active class of menu when page scrolls using id

Tags: jquery, html, css, parallax

I have done a custom menu with a parallax style. The menu is fixed on top and I want to change the active class for the menu when page scrolls. I have done it by click function so by clicking the menu the active class change to that particular menu. I created this menu with id not 'href="#home"'. Most of the code I find is done by href="#" and nav. I don't want the menu to be one with nav navbar.  So can it be done by id?

My codes are below

```js
  $("#home-btn").on('click',function() {
  $('html, body').animate({
   scrollTop : $("#home").offset().top - 10
  }, 1000);
  $('.main-menu ul li').removeClass('active');
  $('#home-btn').parent().addClass('active');
 });
 
 $("#service-btn").on('click',function() {
  $('html, body').animate({
   scrollTop : $("#service").offset().top - 45
  }, 1000);
  $('.main-menu ul li').removeClass('active');
  $('#service-btn').parent().addClass('active');
 });
 
 $("#about-btn").on('click',function() {
  $('html, body').animate({
   scrollTop : $("#about").offset().top - 120
  }, 1000);
  $('.main-menu ul li').removeClass('active');
  $('#about-btn').parent().addClass('active');
 });
 
 $("#contact-btn").on('click',function() {
  $('html, body').animate({
   scrollTop : $("#contact").offset().top - 120
  }, 2000);
  $('.main-menu ul li').removeClass('active');
  $('#contact-btn').parent().addClass('active');
 });
```

```css
.top-adj {
  margin-top: 130px;
}

.main-menu {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  background: #f1f1f1;
}

.main-menu ul {
 display: flex;
 align-items: center;
 justify-content: space-between;
}

.main-menu ul li {
 display: block;
 font-weight: 600;
 margin-left: 25px;
}

.main-menu ul li:first-child {
 margin-left: 0px;
}

.main-menu ul li a {
 color: #000;
 display: block;
 cursor: pointer;
 padding: 25px 10px;
 position: relative;
 border-bottom: 4px solid;
 border-color: transparent;
}

.main-menu ul li a:hover {
 text-decoration: none;
}

.main-menu ul li.active a {
 padding: 25px 10px;
 border-bottom: 4px solid #104377;
}

.section {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
 <div class="main-menu">
   <ul>
       <li class="active"><a id="home-btn">Home</a></li>
         <li><a id="service-btn">Services</a></li>
         <li><a id="about-btn">About</a></li>
         <li><a id="contact-btn">Contact</a></li>
    </ul>
 </div>

<div class="top-adj"></div>
<div class="section" id="home">Home</div>
<div class="section" id="service">Service</div>
<div class="section" id="about">About</div>
<div class="section" id="contact">Contact</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here we have selected all the elements using the `querySelectorAll` method of Vanilla JavaScript.

You can get more idea about `Array.prototype.forEach.call()` [function here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16053357/what-does-foreach-call-do-in-javascript).

We have used `window.onscroll` event to perform our scroll spy in which we have matched the top offset of each section with the scroll position of windows and added class based on it.

```js
(function () {
  var section = document.querySelectorAll(".section");
  var sections = {};
  var i = 0;

  Array.prototype.forEach.call(section, function (e) {
      sections[e.id] = e.offsetTop;
  });

  window.onscroll = function () {
      var scrollPosition = document.documentElement.scrollTop ||
          document.body.scrollTop;

      for (i in sections) {
          if (sections[i] <= scrollPosition) {
              document.querySelector('.active').setAttribute('class', ' ');
              document.querySelector('a[id*=' + i +
                  ']').parentElement.setAttribute('class', 'active');
          }
      }
  };

  // Your code
  $("#home-btn").on('click', function () {
      $('html, body').animate({
          scrollTop: $("#home").offset().top
      }, 1000);
  });

  $("#service-btn").on('click', function () {
      $('html, body').animate({
          scrollTop: $("#service").offset().top
      }, 1000);
  });

  $("#about-btn").on('click', function () {
      $('html, body').animate({
          scrollTop: $("#about").offset().top
      }, 1000);
  });

  $("#contact-btn").on('click', function () {
      $('html, body').animate({
          scrollTop: $("#contact").offset().top
      }, 2000);
  });
})();
```

```css
.top-adj {
  margin-top: 130px;
}

.main-menu {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  background: #f1f1f1;
}

.main-menu ul {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.main-menu ul li {
  display: block;
  font-weight: 600;
  margin-left: 25px;
}

.main-menu ul li:first-child {
  margin-left: 0px;
}

.main-menu ul li a {
  color: #000;
  display: block;
  cursor: pointer;
  padding: 25px 10px;
  position: relative;
  border-bottom: 4px solid;
  border-color: transparent;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.main-menu ul li a:hover {
  text-decoration: none;
}

.main-menu ul li.active a {
  padding: 25px 10px;
  border-bottom: 4px solid #104377;
}

.section {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="main-menu">
   <ul>
     <li class="active"><a id="home-btn">Home</a></li>
     <li><a id="service-btn">Services</a></li>
     <li><a id="about-btn">About</a></li>
     <li><a id="contact-btn">Contact</a></li>
    </ul>
 </div>

<div class="top-adj"></div>
<div class="section" id="home">Home</div>
<div class="section" id="service">Service</div>
<div class="section" id="about">About</div>
<div class="section" id="contact">Contact</div>
```

I hope this helps.

Comment: Read question ` created this menu with id not 'href="#home"'. Most of the code I find is done by href="#" and nav. I don't want the menu to be one with nav navbar. So can it be done by id?`

Comment: there is a bug. clicking on menu active class in not active for that class. Please click contact button the active class is showing in about

Comment: Hi, @AkhilAravind Thank you for highlighting. I have updated my code.

Comment: @User113 I have updated my code based on your requirements. Please let me know if you have any concerns.

Comment: @Viral still you are not using `ID`, you are using `data-href`

Comment: when i put this code on my webpage it's not working. Also can you pls do it in id.

Comment: @User113 I have updated my code and also I have checked this demo on my local system as well. Please let me know if you have any concerns!

Comment: @Viral It works but active class is not showing correctly. When click on about link active class shows on service. Please fix

Comment: @User113 It seems to be working correctly for me. Can you please regenerate this situation on codepen or jsfiddle?

Answer (score 0):

This is the edited code of the upper comment.

```js
(function () {
  var section = document.querySelectorAll(".section");
  var sections = {};
  var i = 0;

  Array.prototype.forEach.call(section, function (e) {
      sections[e.id] = e.offsetTop;
  });

  window.onscroll = function () {
      var scrollPosition = document.documentElement.scrollTop ||
          document.body.scrollTop;

      for (i in sections) {
          if (sections[i] <= scrollPosition) {
              $('.nav-item').parent().removeClass('active');
              document.querySelector('a[id*=' + i +
                  ']').parentElement.setAttribute('class', 'active');
          }
      }
  };

  // Your code
  $("#home-btn").on('click', function () {
      $('html, body').animate({
          scrollTop: $("#home").offset().top
      }, 1000);
  });

  $("#service-btn").on('click', function () {
      $('html, body').animate({
          scrollTop: $("#service").offset().top
      }, 1000);
  });

  $("#about-btn").on('click', function () {
      $('html, body').animate({
          scrollTop: $("#about").offset().top
      }, 1000);
  });

  $("#contact-btn").on('click', function () {
      $('html, body').animate({
          scrollTop: $("#contact").offset().top
      }, 2000);
  });
})();
```

```css
.top-adj {
  margin-top: 40px;
}

.main-menu {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  background: #f1f1f1;
}

.main-menu ul {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.main-menu ul li {
  display: block;
  font-weight: 600;
  margin-left: 25px;
}

.main-menu ul li:first-child {
  margin-left: 0px;
}

.main-menu ul li a {
  color: #000;
  display: block;
  cursor: pointer;
  padding: 4px 10px;
  position: relative;
  border-bottom: 4px solid;
  border-color: transparent;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.main-menu ul li a:hover {
  text-decoration: none;
}

.main-menu ul li.active a {
  padding: 4px 10px;
  border-bottom: 4px solid #104377;
}

.section {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
  padding-top:40px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="main-menu">
   <ul>
     <li><a class="nav-item" id="home-btn">Home</a></li>
     <li><a class="nav-item" id="service-btn">Services</a></li>
     <li><a class="nav-item" id="about-btn">About</a></li>
     <li><a class="nav-item" id="contact-btn">Contact</a></li>
    </ul>
 </div>

<div class="top-adj"></div>
<div class="section" id="home">Home</div>
<div class="section" id="service">Service</div>
<div class="section" id="about">About</div>
<div class="section" id="contact">Contact</div>
```