# Upload folder javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I am looking online how to upload a folder of images and display them using JavaScript, and I am seeing this code repeatedly:

```
var inps = document.querySelectorAll('input');
[].forEach.call(inps, function(inp) {
  inp.onchange = function(e) {
    console.log(this.files);
  };
});
```

Firstly, it doesn't work on my Google Chrome (it is not logging anything), and more importantly, what is this method of doing

```
[].forEach.call
```

What does this mean? (to use [] before forEach)?

Comment: `[].forEach.call` or `Array.prototype.forEach.call` invokes the array prototype forEach method for a given context, in this case `inps`. `document.querySelectorAll` returns an object that can be treated as an array but it is not actually an array (it returns `NodeList`). In such cases, you can use the prototype method and call them on an object of your choosing.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What does \[\].forEach.call() do in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16053357/what-does-foreach-call-do-in-javascript)

Comment: This code must be accompanied by HTML that contains at least one `<input type="file">` element and it's triggered when you manually select a file in the browser.

Answer (score 0):

**BLOB** - Binary Large Object

If you want preview loaded images, you should create blob.
URL will correct after save image in file base or database.

[my GIT hub with example for only one picture](https://github.com/shturmavik/iavatar)

[image]

`[].forEach.call` it's just rule and you got answer upper.

[developer.mozilla.org -> [].forEach.call](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach)

```js
let inps = document.querySelectorAll('input');
[].forEach.call(inps, function(inp) {
  inp.onchange = function(e) {
    console.log(URL.createObjectURL(this.files[0])) //create BLOB for preview if need
    for (file of this.files) {
      setFiles(file); //parsing all uploaded files
      createLIST(file, this.files.length);
    }
  };
});

//save all file to database by your URL -> URL_FOR_PROCESSING_POST
function setFiles(file) {
  console.log(file);
  let request = new XMLHttpRequest();
  let formData = new FormData();
  formData.append(file.name, file);
  request.open('POST', 'URL_FOR_GET_POST');
  request.send(formData);
}

arResult = [];
function createLIST(file, count) {
  let html = '<ul>';
  for (let item in file) {
    html += `<li><div>${item}</div> <div>${file[item]}</div></li>`;
  }
  html += '</ul>';
  arResult.push(html);
  if (arResult.length === count) {
    document.querySelector('#output-data').innerHTML = arResult.join('');
  }
}
```

```css
.output-data {
  counter-reset: section;
}
.output-data ul {
  border-bottom: 1px solid grey;
  padding-bottom: 1rem;
}
.output-data ul:before {
  counter-increment: section;
  content: "File " counter(section) ": ";
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 20px;
  color: green;
  margin-bottom: 1rem;
  display: block;
}
.output-data li {
  display: flex;
  padding-bottom: 0.25rem;
}
.output-data li div:first-child {
  font-weight: bold;
  flex: 0 1 200px;
}
.output-data li div:last-child {
  text-align: left;
}
```

```html
<input type="file" name="file" webkitdirectory directory>

<div id="output-data" class="output-data"></div>
```

Comment: Thanks. Unfortunately the console.log is not logging anything so I don't think its working. Its not iterating through the [].foreach.call although i copy and pasted your code. any ideas what could be happening? (ive noticed that the nodelist is empty when i console.log(inps)

Comment: I corrected my answer and added link to my codepen.io -> https://codepen.io/Shturmavik/pen/ExyrRry