# Replacing `<span>`with text node: Is it a programmer error, or a browser error?

Tags: javascript, dom, replace, collections

I'm trying to replace some placeholders in my HTML that look like `<span id="Something" />`. Using the following JavaScript code only replaced the first occurrence, and I wonder why:

```javascript
function set_placeholder(cls, txt)
{
    txt = document.createTextNode(txt);
    for (var e of document.getElementsByClassName(cls)) {
        e.parentNode.replaceChild(txt, e);
    }
}
```

It seems the collection is unable to locate the next match after the `span` has been replaced.

So I tried to *insert* the text instead, using this variant:

```javascript
function set_placeholder(cls, txt)
{
    for (var e of document.getElementsByClassName(cls)) {
        e.innerText = txt;
    }
}
```

Now all occurrences are replaced, making me wonder whether it is my fault, or the browser's (Firefox 102) when the first variant fails.

### HTML Sample

The actual HTML is much more complex, but here's some sample:

```html
<html>
 <p><span class="ph-customer" /> bestellte am <span class="ph-customer-date" /> folgende Artikel:</p>
<!-- ... -->
 <table>
  <tr>
    <td><span class="ph-customer-date" />,
    <span class="ph-customer-name" /></td>
  </tr>
 </table>
<!-- ... -->
</html>
```

So for example the `ph-customer-date` occurs twice, but calling `set_placeholder('ph-customer-date', '30.12.2023')` would only replace the first occurrence.

Comment: Can you please add the relevant HTML to the question so we can create a debuggable working example of the problem

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/replaceChild `Warning: If the new node is already present somewhere else in the DOM, it is first removed from that position.`. I think this might explain your problem?

Comment: Move `document.createTextNode(txt)` into the loop

Comment: @Konrad I had tried that, but that's not the root cause of the problem it seems.

Comment: @RobinZigmond If it were the case, the I would see only the *last* `span` replaced, right? I think the problem is with iterating the collection after replacing.

Comment: The duplicate is only half of your problem. The other half is indeed the iteration after replacement. `getElementsByClassName()` returns a live collection, so when you replace the first element, it no longer matches the class name so all the elements in the collection move up one. That means that the iterator over the collection skips every other match. As there's two matched elements, that means only the first element gets replaced. If you had four matched elements, you'd find that the third one was replaced by the text node, the first one was removed, and the other two were untouched.

Comment: I understood the concept of live collection a bit, but I was surprised that replacing the "first match", the "second match" could not be located any more, even though it still exists. That *could* be an implementation bug. However if I had manipulated the second match before actually locating it, I would understand. Also there is no error thrown or whatever when the "match" in the collection could not be found.

Comment: I still think that this question could be answered, and also it's less complex than the suggested duplicate (that does a different thing IMHO). Finally I fail to see the live collection in there.

Comment: That's because the "second match" immediately became the "first match" once the original first match was changed to no longer match. However, once you are done with the first iteration, your iterator will have already moved on to the second item, which would be what originally was the third, causing the originally-second to fall through the cracks. You can copy the live collection into an array first and the operate on that (wrap it in `Array.from`). - I do agree though that it's a bit surprising that this happens with an iterator too and not only with an index, I thought it'd be smarter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

actually in your case it is not an iterator propblem is much more a logical problem let me explain:

```
function set_placeholder(cls, txt)
{
    // ok wrong place and wrong variable name but nevermind
    //(you need to create the text node everytime you need to replace an element)
    txt = document.createTextNode(txt);
    
    for (var e of document.getElementsByClassName(cls)) {
        //here start the paradox( just like a wormhole and alternative realities ^_^ )
        // when you call the replaceChild your next document.getElementsByClassName(cls)
        // will return a different list (an alternative reality) 
        // and your next element (e) will be different from what you expect
        e.parentNode.replaceChild(txt, e);
    }
}
```

so for make it short this is the most similar approach to your version:

```
function set_placeholder(cls, txt=''){
  var e =document.getElementsByClassName(cls);
  while( e.length>0){
    e[0].parentNode.replaceChild(document.createTextNode(txt),e[0]);
    e=document.getElementsByClassName(cls);
  }
}
```

and this is a more compact version of the same approach:

```
function set_placeholder(cls, txt=''){
  while( e=document.querySelector("."+cls)){
    e.parentNode.replaceChild(document.createTextNode(txt),e);
  }
}
```

plus you could refine the code limiting action to a certain container and not to the whole document in this way:

```
function set_placeholder(cls, txt='',elementContainer=document){
  while( e=elementContainer.querySelector("."+cls)){
    e.parentNode.replaceChild(elementContainer.createTextNode(txt),e);
  }
}
```

Comment: Still it's not quite clear to me, why I must create a different text node when I replace a child; maybe it's because I think about the resulting HTML where having the *same text* is not a problem at all. The other misleading thing might be a Perl `foreach $var (get_some_array())` where you can modify the elements of `@ARRAY` in the loop, but still get all the elements originally returned by `get_some_array()` one after the other. Maybe I didn't correctly understand *live collection*.

Comment: you need to create a new text element each time because using e.parentNode.replaceChild(txtNode,e);
in the first iteration the code will replace txtNode with e
but in subsequent iterations if you don't create a new one, the txtNode will be "moved" (detached) from its current position and replaced with e
and therefore in the end you will find all the elements deleted except the last one in which the txtNode will end up.
in short your txtNode will eat every element but last one (like Pac-Man eat dots on his road ^_^)

Comment: I guess my problem was that I did imagine the DOM tree to be an XML text document (in such an editor could easily search&replace strings), just what the browser seems to "see". So I had no idea that inserting (replacing) the same "text" element multiple time could cause any problem (aprt those with the "live collection").

Answer (score 7):

The implementation is correct, and has been the same for 2 decades. What you are observing is that you are dealing with a live `HTMLCollection` and `for` will use the `HTMLCollection.prototype[Symbol.iterator]` to get the members. As others pointed correctly, `replaceChild` will pop the 0th item, and 1st will be 0th and 2nd will be first. Instead, cast it to something static:

`Array.from(...)`

Your second example works because it modifies the contents of object reference (in this case the `span` node) and not remove the pointer to the object from the `HTMLCollection`; such 'safe' methods are `innerHTML`, `textContent`, `innerText`. You will have the same problem with `outerHTML`, which essentially removes the pointer.

Keeping in mind `HTMLCollections` being live, you also need to watch for `NodeList` that can exhibit similar behavior based on live or not. `Node.childNodes` returns a live one, but everything else with `document.querySelector` and `document.querySelectorAll` will return static `NodeList`

It is generally safe to cast them to regular arrays via `Array.from`

OR use `document.querySelectorAll(".whateverclass")`

```js
Array.from(document.getElementsByTagName("DIV")).forEach((div, i) => {
  if(!i){
    //method1 - DOES NOT WORK
    for (const span of div.getElementsByClassName("a")) {
      div.replaceChild(document.createTextNode("!"), span)
    }
  } else {
    //method2 - WORKS
    for (const span of Array.from(div.getElementsByClassName("b"))) {
      div.replaceChild(document.createTextNode("!"), span)
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<div>
  <span class="a">x</span>
  <span class="a">y</span>
  <span class="a">z</span>
</div>

<div>
  <span class="b">u</span>
  <span class="b">v</span>
  <span class="b">w</span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
const CLASSNAME = 'txt';
/*
 */

function set_placeholder(cls, txt = '') {
  let textNode = document.createTextNode(txt);
  let elements = Array.from(document.getElementsByClassName(cls));

  [].forEach.call(elements, (elem) => {
    elem.parentElement.replaceChild(textNode, elem);
    textNode = document.createTextNode(txt);
  });
}


document.querySelector('button').onclick = function() {
  set_placeholder.call(set_placeholder, CLASSNAME, 'new text');
}
```

```css
p {
  margin: calc(1rem / 10);
}
```

```html
<div>
  <p>Spans: </p>
   <span class="txt">a</span> <br />
   <span class="txt">b</span> <br />
   <span class="txt">c</span>
</div>


<button>Replace</button>
```

Gathering elements via `document.querySelectorAll` or `document.getElementsByClassName` returns the NodeList of elements found, which is a mutated version of an array. Therefore, with the use of `[...]` (spread syntax) or `Array.from`, the issue can be fixed. But after all, this is intended behavior. Hope this helped.

Comment: I'm a but confused about `[].forEach.call(...)`: Isn't that an iterator over an empty array? Why not `elements.forEach.call(...)`? I saw the explanation at https://stackoverflow.com/a/16053538/6607497, so it's basically calling a "static" method of `Array`?

Comment: Didn't mean to put the `Array.from` at `elements`. `[].forEach.call(...)` would have  only been necessary due to its array type being NodeList. Only use that method if the regular array isn't iterable. Or just use the spread syntax, e.g, `[...elements].forEach(...)`.
# **EDIT**
  For loops also work for NodeLists, refer to the following script for an example:

Answer (score 1):

First using `e.parentNode.replaceChild(txt, e)` you are replacing the `span` with the `txt` node (so the `span` itself is deleted).

Second, because new `txt` node is assigned outside the loop, it is just the one element. The next iteration(s) will just replace the next span with this `txt` node.

Furthermore using empty spans with `<span .../>` is not handled well by browsers (for multiple elements it renders them not the way you may expect. This is the actual culprit with your code. See [this stackblitz project](https://stackblitz.com/edit/js-qfzgr9?file=index.js)) for explanation. Better use `<span></span>`.

I'd say just setting `textContent` for each `span` would be sufficient (or `innerText` if you need to be aware of the rendered appearance of the text). It keeps the `span` (including possible styling) intact.

Here is a snippet that does what you seem to want, either by filling the spans with text or replacing them (using [`replaceWith`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/replaceWith)):

```js
// keep element[className]
function replaceTxtFor(className, nwText) {
  document.querySelectorAll(className)
    .forEach(elem => elem.textContent = nwText);
}

// replace element[className]
function replaceElementWithText(className, nwText) {
  document.querySelectorAll(className)
    .forEach(elem => 
       elem.replaceWith(document.createTextNode(nwText)));
}

setTimeout(() => {
  replaceTxtFor(`.ph-customer-date`, `14.01.2024`);
  replaceElementWithText(`.ph-customer-name`, `Na also`); },
  1000);
```

```css
.ph-customer-date,
.ph-customer-name
{
  color: green;
}
```

```html
<p>
  <!-- use <span></span> here -->
  <span class="ph-customer-name"></span> bestellte am
  <span class="ph-customer-date"></span> folgende Artikel:
</p>

<table>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <span class="ph-customer-date"></span>,
      <span class="ph-customer-name"></span>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Actually replacing the span was intended, but I don't get why `replaceChild` would *move* the `txt` node instead of replacing the next `span` with the same `txt`. Using `<span .../>`in HTML was probably that every current browser does understand the XML syntax, too.

Comment: 'move'  may not be the right word here, sorry. I adjusted my answer, and by the way provided an extra function in the snippet that replaces the spans. Concerning XML syntax: see [this stackblitz example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/js-qfzgr9?file=index.js) for what the browser makes from `<span />`.